# upload pypi error:HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information

Tags: python, windows, setup.py, pypi

I have created a user authentication file,this way:

```
[distutils]
index-servers=pypi

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username: <username>
password: <password>
```

Comment: What was the command? Can you [edit] and copy/paste full text from the terminal?

Comment: Where have you stored this file? What platform / operating system are you using?